# How to populate mat-select with angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hey I'm trying to use angular material and I'm having an issue. In my project I get movies details such as title,year,genre and so on. I'm trying to make an edit popup and when I got to the genre edit I got a little problem. how can I populate the select line with genres the movie already has?

lets say for example I want the default value to be: "Action,Comedy".

my html:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Genre" [formControl]="genre" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let genre of genresList" value="Action,Comedy" >{{genre}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="genre.hasError('required')">
      Title is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

component:

```
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedMovie: MyMovie;


  title:FormControl;
  year:FormControl;
  runtime:FormControl;
  genre:FormControl;
  director:FormControl;


  genresList: string[] = ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance'];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.selectedMovie = dataService.selectedMovie;

    this.title = new FormControl(this.selectedMovie.Title, [
      Validators.required
    ]);
    this.year = new FormControl(this.selectedMovie.Year, [
      Validators.required
    ]);
    this.runtime = new FormControl(this.selectedMovie.Runtime, [
      Validators.required
    ]);
    this.genre = new FormControl("this.selectedMovie.Genre", [
      Validators.required
    ]);
    this.director = new FormControl(this.selectedMovie.Director, [
      Validators.required
    ]);


  }
```

Appreciate any help! thanks

update:

```
this.dataService.getMovie(this.moviesToLoad[i]).subscribe(res => {

        this.movie = {
           id: this.id,
           Title: res.Title,
           Year: res.Year,
           Runtime: res.Runtime,
           Genre: res.Genre.split(","),
           Director: res.Director
          }
```

res is just string which im trying to change to array, something wrong over since i get only the first element of the array in the default mat-select.. how can i fix that?

Comment: this is the data I want to be shown as default

Comment: what do you mean? how can i transfer this to a formGroup?

Comment: you solved my problem bro i really thank you, but i can only see the first element in the genre array i get in the mat-select field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be creating a `FormGroup` instead of individual `FormControl`s.

`Genre` in your Movie is a `string` but the multiple select list will need an array of string to show multiple values. Also, looks like there's a space between the `genres`(`Action, Crime`) which when trimmed will create an extra starting space in `Crime`. To fix that, you'll need to `split` by `,` and then apply `map` on the array elements to remove the extra space by using `trim`. This will be done by this like:

```
genre: [this.selectedMovie.Genre.split(',').map(genre => genre.trim()), [Validators.required]],
```

So your code will look something like:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...
selectedMovie: MyMovie;
movieForm: FormGroup;
genresList = ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance'];

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private dataService: DataService
) {}

ngOnInit() {

  this.dataService.getMovie('anyIndexHere')
    .subscribe(selectedMovie => {

      this.selectedMovie = {
        id: 'Some ID',
        ...selectedMovie
      }

      this.movieForm = this.fb.group({
        title: [this.selectedMovie.Title, [Validators.required]],
        year: [this.selectedMovie.Year, [Validators.required]],
        runtime: [this.selectedMovie.Runtime, [Validators.required]],
        genre: [this.selectedMovie.Genre.split(',').map(genre => genre.trim()), [Validators.required]],
        director: [this.selectedMovie.Director, [Validators.required]],
      });

    });
}
```

Since we're already assigning the default value to the `genre` `FormControl`, it will be selected by default in your template.

So in your template, you'll now be using the attribute binding syntax(`[formGroup]="movieForm"`) to bind to the form. And then for the `mat-select` since you'll be specifying the `formControlName` as `genre` which is the `FormControl` for the Genre field, you'll see the Genre's selected by default.

So your template would look something like:

```
<form [formGroup]="movieForm">
  ...
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Movie Genre" formControlName="genre" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let genre of genresList" [value]="genre">
        {{genre}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  ...
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-eg-dynamic-select-value?file=app/select-form-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: thanks a lot!. still, how can I make a default value to be shown in the select line? right now thats Movie Genre, I want my options to be selected even before i chose them, from the data i get.

Comment: im now trying to change the string i get from api to array of genres. something doesnt work,  i update the main post please have a look... and thanks so much!