# How we dynamically Select Some Options In multiple Selection List In Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a form for editing data. In it is a drop-down list of users checkboxes, multiple select. I get the previously selected options array [] from the DB in the profile data object and I want to show those users as checked in the edit profile form. When the user is editing their profile they can see what they previously selected.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select 
      placeholder="Users" 
      formControlName="usersdata" 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUser" multiple>
      <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let datausers of users" 
        (click)="clickedOption()" 
        [value]="datausers.user_id">
          {{datausers.employee_name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I have this for capturing the array of `empData`. that are in the DB:

```
empData = [];

this.https.get < any > (this.selectedUser_API).subscribe((response) => {
  this.empData = response.empData;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate mat-select with angular material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672346/how-to-populate-mat-select-with-angular-material)

Comment: You might want to create a ReactiveForm and then call the `patchValue`/`setValue` method on it to initialize the `FormControl`'s value.

Comment: Ya I will try but its not work.

for (let i = 0; i < this.empData.length; i++) {       this.EditProjectsForm.controls['usersdata'].setValue(this.empData[i].project_id);
   
    
    }

Answer (score 1):

In your .html file

```
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select 
      placeholder="Users" 
      formControlName="usersdata" 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" multiple>
      <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let datausers of users" 
        (click)="clickedOption()" 
        [value]="datausers.user_id">
          {{datausers.employee_name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

In your .ts file

```
selectedUsers = []
this.https.get < any > (this.selectedUser_API).subscribe((response) => {
  this.empData = response.empData;
  this.selectedUsers =  this.empData.map(
      data => data.user_id
    )
//assuming this.empData is a user object array.
});
```

selectedUsers should contain user_id's not user objects.